# How to update all records matching a filter in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to update only one column of multiple records. I can achieve the below:

```
var test = _items.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ItemId== entity.Id);
            test.First(x => x.ItemId== entity.Id).Name= "Hello";
```

The above `Name` column gets updated, but it only updates the first record because I specified just the first.

I actually want to update all the records that matches the `Id` instead of just the first one.

I tried to use `All` as follows

`test.All(x => x.ItemId== entity.Id).Name= "Hello";`

but on the `Name` column it gives me an error saying "bool does not contain a definition of Name", but with `First()` it works.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: LINQ doesn't modify data and ORMs like EF work one object at a time.  If you want to update multiple rows, don't use an ORM.

Comment: `.All` checks, if all items of an enumerable/queryable match a given condition. The result is either `true` or `false`. Neither has a `Name` property. - you probably want something like `foreach(var item in test) { item.Name = "Hello"; }`.

Comment: How do you iterate over an `IEnumerable`? I usually use `foreach` myself... But @PanagiotisKanavos is right, this sounds like something that should be done at the database level.

Comment: Btw. `.First` "works", because _that_ returns the _first_ item of an enumerable/queryable that matches a given condition. Which in this case _does_ have a `Name` property (apparently).

Comment: @Corak i used your foreach approach and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think you may be looking for this but it’s not vanilla EF and required an additional (previoulsy open source) library: https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update